# Is this sentence an example of double negative?

Tags: double-negation

> and no woman will not come within 1 mile of you

The other person wanted to say - no woman will come within a mile around you.

Comment: What made you suspect it was not?

Comment: Not a real question. Classic NARQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that seems like a straightforward example of a double negative.

It's probably worth noting, however, that "within a mile of you" is the usual phrase in this context; "within a mile [or whatever distance] around you" is seldom heard in native English speech. A grammatically correct and natural-sounding way of expressing your point is

> No woman will come within a mile of you.

Comment: As an additional note, the double negative as it stands in the original quote seems very unnatural to me. If I were to use a double negative in that sentence (in a very colloquial manner, as double negatives are), I would never say ‘will not’, but rather ‘won’t’. I’d probably also add ‘ain’t’ at the head of the clause: _And ain’t no woman won’t come within a mile of you_ (or something along those lines). ‘Will not’ seems oddly formal for a double negative.